# How can I use srcset images on blogger.com in different aspect ratios; specifically in 1:1, 4:3 and 16:9?

Tags: blogger, aspect-ratio, srcset

I've read somewhere on https://developers.google.com' target='_blank' > google blog; I couldn't find exact url, that it's a good practice for to provide an image with aspect ratio of 1:1, 4:3, and 16:9. My question is "How can I use srcset images on blogger.com in aspect ratios of 1:1, 4:3 and 16:9 ?

It's total headache, I'm not a developer I don't know about coding. Here's what I suspect the code I'm currently using;

<img expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.firstImage' expr:srcset='sourceSet(data:post.firstImage, [200,320,400,560,640], &quot;90:90&quot;)' height='90' sizes='(max-width: 800px) 100vw, (min-width: 801px) calc(32vw + 200px), 400px' width='90'/>

But it's not working, it's giving me 5 srcset images of the aspect ratio ie. 1:1. See my [blogs](https://mausiqi-lyrics.blogspot.com) sidebar to understand what I mean.